# If statement in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to run following code:

```
@IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
if nameField.text == "" || usernameField.text == "" || passwordField.text == "" || emailField.text == ""{
    println("error")
}
```

But I am getting compiler error on XCode 6.

```
Invalid character in source file
Expected '{' after 'if' condition
Braced block of statements is an unused closure
```

How can I resolve them ?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the code in the screenshot. Update your question with the proper code.

Comment: plz add space where your condition ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably accidentally entered a non-breaking space character (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> on OS X) or some other invisible character where the arrow is pointing, i.e. just before `emailField` in the `if`.

Try replacing it with a plain space character.